# shap.force_plot() raises Exeption: In v0.20 force_plot now requires the base value as the first parameter

Tags: decision-tree, xgboost, lightgbm, catboost

I'm using Catboost and would like to visualize shap_values:

```
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier
model = CatBoostClassifier(iterations=300)
model.fit(X, y,cat_features=cat_features)

pool1 = Pool(data=X, label=y, cat_features=cat_features)
shap_values = model.get_feature_importance(data=pool1, fstr_type='ShapValues', verbose=10000)

shap_values.shape
Output: (32769, 10)
X.shape
Output: (32769, 9)
```

Then I do the following and an exception is raised:

```
shap.initjs()
shap.force_plot(shap_values[0,:-1], X.iloc[0,:])
```

**Exception: In v0.20 force_plot now requires the base value as the first parameter! Try shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values) or for multi-output models try shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value[0], shap_values[0]).**

The following works, but I would like to make force_plot() work:

```
shap.initjs()
shap.summary_plot(shap_values[:,:-1], X)
```

I read the Documentation but can't make sense of explainer. I tried:

```
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model,data=pool1)
#Also tried:
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model,data=X)
```

but I get: **TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''**

Can anyone point me in the right direction? THX

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error as below-

> Exception: In v0.20 force_plot now requires the base value as the
>   first parameter! Try shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value,
>   shap_values) or for multi-output models try
>   shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value[0], shap_values[0]).

This helped me resolve the issue-

```
import shap
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model,data=X)
shap.initjs()
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value[0],X.iloc[0,:])
```

Also for the below issue -

> TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the
>   inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to
>   the casting rule ''safe''

Check your data, if it contains any NaN's or missing values.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values.values[0, :], X.iloc[0, :])
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'.`

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Sparsha's answer, since I was still getting errors, what worked for me was:

```
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model, data = X)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_train)
shap.initjs()
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values[0], feature_names = explainer.data_feature_names)
```